# Cannot delete a folder with undefined number (many) of files in it

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems

I have a folder with many files inside, i can't known number of files because I can't do `ls` or other listing command.

These files are temporary so I tried `rm -rf my-folder` but it takes too many time, and I get disconnected from the server.

I reconnect and restart the command, but maybe it's useless, if the `rm` cmd have to read the entire directory before deleting files.

OS : Debian 10

Anyone to help ? Ty

Comment: Set your ssh client to keep alive the connection. Or put the `rm` command in background. And yes, it take good amount of time.  I am not aware of other safe utils to do this.

Comment: You can try `nohup rm -rf my-folder > /dev/null 2>&1 &` to allow the `rm` command to continue running even if you get disconnected. Alternately, use something like `tmux` or `screen` that will let you re-attach to a terminal session after you get disconnected.

Comment: larsks `-f` is always a bad idea to use it in first place. most files can be deleted without a hazzle by using `find` or even `xargs` remember -f can freak your system, using screen can solve a timeout issue

Answer (score 2):

If there are a large number of files in the folder, what I would do is:

Delete files in `my-folder` by having `find` -delete

```
find /path/to/my-folder -type f -delete
```

Delete files in `my-folder` by having `find` execute `rm`

```
find /path/to/my-folder -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```

If there are lot of subdirectories, `find` by depth first deleting directories:

```
find /path/to/my-folder -depth -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Waited for hours to « rm -rf some-dir » to finish.